# Update a Python dictionary values from other dictionay

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary, say dict1, with some key-value pairs. I'd like to create a new dictionary dict2, with the same keys, but different values, based on values in dict1. For example:

```
dict1 = {'A':4, 'B':7, 'C':5}
```

dict2 is somewhat like `{'A':(4/t^2), 'B':7/(t^2), 'C':5/(t^2)}`, etc. based on some `t`.

So the new `dict2` values are created from `dict1` values, for corresponding keys. I have tried looping using items, etc. but without much success.

Comment: Or specifically for your setup: `{k: v / (t ** 2) for k, v in my_dictionary.items()}`

Comment: Thank you Martijn very much!!!